# Set Content Type for Specific MultiPart in rest assured

Tags: rest, testing, rest-assured

I am using 2 multiparts ( 1 is a file the other is a form-data )
For the file I am using the default content type but (multipart/form-data) but for the other I need to use `application/json`

I don't know how to set content type for that specific multipart/fpr, data ===

[image]

This is what I have done -

```
 Response resp =  RestAssured.given().baseUri(UPLOAD)
               .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=--abcd")
               .multiPart("files",new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") +picPath))
               .multiPart("JSON_DATA",JSON_DATA )
               .post().then().extract().response();
```

But this is the request that has been generated --

---

```
            Content-Disposition: form-data; boundary=--abcd; name = files; filename =Photo.png
            Content-Type: application/octet-stream
            /../../../Photo.png
            ------------
            Content-Disposition: form-data; boundary=--abcd; name = JSON_Data; filename = file
            **Content-Type: text/plain**
            {.......}
```

HOW DO I SET THE 2ND ONE TO application/json instead of text/plainm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define content-type for each part like this, no need put `form-data` in header

```
given().log().all()
.multiPart("file", file)
.multiPart("JSON_DATA", JSON_DATA, "application/json")
.post();
```

Comment: @DemonSlayer Could you accept my answer? thank you.